# How I Get Treeview Multiple Node value in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I did't know get values from treeview control multiple child nodes when TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged Event .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a foreach on `selectedNode.Nodes` to get the value of each child node.